# Accessing iOS app sandbox documents with Windows

Tags: ios, node.js

Is there a tool or node-js module like adb (android debug bridge) for iOS,
which can push/pull any files in App sandbox Documents folder (files can be seen by iTunes/iBrowser/iExplorer).
something like https://github.com/appcelerator/node-ios-device but it only support Mac OS X.

Comment: not sure why nobody answers, maybe the question is unclear or too specific.